# PHP gearman workers not detected

Tags: php, gearman

I've upgraded gearman from and old pre 1.0 version used in CentOS 6.4 to 1.1.8, and after I also upgraded PHP bindings to 1.1.1, php workers are no longer working - they don't process any jobs, nor get counted by gearman itself. Here's the code I'm using for workers:

```
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();
$gmworker->addServer("localhost", "4730");
$gmworker->addFunction("checkHost", "dummy");

while($gmworker->work()) {}

function dummy() {
    echo "job\n";
    return 'ok';
}
```

`echo status | nc localhost 4730;` shows 200+ jobs of checkHost type, and 0 workers. When I start a simple nodejs client:

```
var gearman = new (require("node-gearman"))('localhost', 4730);

gearman.registerWorker("checkHost", function(payload, worker){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('end');
        worker.end('end');
    }, 1000);
});
```

jobs get processed normally. So apparently there are some problems with the PHP binding? How do I fix this?